# Designing a circuit that opens when less than 12 volts are applied and closes when more than 12 are applied

Tags: voltage, current, diodes, circuit-design, semiconductors

I'm looking to build a circuit where current only flows when there is a potential difference across the entire circuit of more than 12 volts (+- 0.1 V). I also need there to be only a small amount of resistance across the part of the circuit that controls whether current will flow, in order to prevent overheating. I'm not sure what I should use to control this; I was thinking of using a zener diode, but cannot find any with a forward voltage above 7V. I'm thinking that there might be some other type of semiconductor I could use, but I'm not sure what it would be. Perhaps I could use a zener diode but put it in reverse orientation rather than forward? I'm not sure how much resistance that would add however. What would you guys recommend using?
[image]

Comment: Any comparator can act as low side switch up to xx mA using any Vref with input scaled down to Vref so if V+>V- the output goes from open to closed =0V then load to V+ and output

Comment: How many wires? For example do you want this to be like a switch with just two wires that comes on when the supply is more than 12V? And how much current?

Comment: How much current must be switched? How sloppy can the tripvoltage be (12 +- 2v?)? How fast must the switching occur, once the tripvoltage is detected?

Comment: @JackCreasey exactly. Just two wires and it switches on when a high enough voltage is achieved.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the trip voltage would need to be +- 0.25 volts at most. The switching doesn't need to be too fast, up to a couple seconds would be fine. There would be anywhere from 1-10 amps flowing through the circuit when closed.

Comment: 2 wires makes it 100 times harder to design.

Comment: zener diodes are available above 7v, 10v and 12V are fairly common.

Comment: @Jasen it could have more if necessary. Two is the minimum but I could add more.

Comment: adding wire to "+"  makes ir easier to determine the voltage (especially while the switch is on)  and also allow power to operate the switch.

Comment: @Jasen I could add a wire to the +. What kind of switch would I use?

Comment: for switch mosfet,  bipolar transistor or relay, for voltage sensor TL431 is good choice especially since you want better than 1% accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below schematic offers a high current sink and MOSFET gate protection and about 250mV of hysteresis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ2Rr9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you could do this perhaps, I've drawn it rotated 180 degrees from your diagram.

[image: schematic]

Comment: But this needs 3 wires, so does not meet the requirements.

Comment: How do you protect the MOSFET gate if Vcc goes way above 12 volts? OP did imply the source voltage was not regulated.

Comment: The source voltage would go as high as 16V, but no higher.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but couldn't the current take the outside path going through R1 and R2 even when the voltage is far below 12V?

Comment: yes, current will flow from `+` to `-` - about 2mA but no current will flow through the load.

Comment: sparky's version of my circuit is better behaved.